# Template specialization and SFINAE on VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, variadic-templates

I'm using VS2013 (update 4), and I'm having trouble compiling the following variadic template code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Variadic template "multiwrite" for writing a string to multiple different streams
template <typename T>
void mwrite(T value, std::ostream& os) { os << value; }
template <typename T, typename... SS>
void mwrite(T value, std::ostream& os, SS... streams) { mwrite(value, os); mwrite(value, streams...); }

// Main
int main()
{
    std::ostream& out = std::cout;
    std::ostream& err = std::cerr;
    mwrite(std::string("Hello"), out, err);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
error C2280: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
 see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ostream'
```

I have tried implementing this function with other types than std::ostreams and those work fine. Also, I know about the fact that ostreams don't have a copy-constructor, and at first I suspected that that was the problem here.

However, then I tried explicitly specifying the template parameters at the call point in main:

```
mwrite<std::string, std::ostream&>(std::string("Hello"), out, err);
```

and this works fine as well. So, I find myself in the situation that the compiler fails on a particular specialization (the one with pass-by-value ostreams), whereas there does exist a specialization that is perfectly legal (with pass-by-reference ostreams). I am reluctant to blame the compiler, so my question is: is this behavior somehow still SFINAE-conforming? Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SFINAE. And in any event there's no substitution failure here. SFINAE has to do with template argument substitution creating an ill-formed function declaration. There's nothing ill-formed about the signature `void mwrite(std::string, std::ostream&, std::ostream);`.

The problem is that you are passing `SS` by value, and so end up attempting to make a copy of a stream. Streams are not copyable. Pass by reference instead:

```
template <typename T, typename... SS>
void mwrite(T value, std::ostream& os, SS&... streams) { mwrite(value, os); mwrite(value, streams...); }
//                                       ^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort! This works indeed. Your solution has also uncovered my thinking error: I thought that a general type could be specialized to a reference, but this is not the case it appears. Thanks again!

I would like to give you an upvote, but I can't because I'm new --> somebody please do this :-)